# Selenium Webdriver Communication Error

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm doing a java project which uses selenium web driver to automatically do tasks in a website, but getting errors.

Set `System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","path to chrome driver");`

Have this method

```
public boolean openBrowserAndLoadUrl(String url) {          
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.addArguments("--disable-extensions","--start-maximized");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
        if(driver==null)
            return false;
        driver.get("https://www.google.co.in");
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        return true;
}
```

pom.xml

```
<org.seleniumhq-version>2.53.1</org.seleniumhq-version>

<!-- Selenium -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-chrome-driver</artifactId>
        <version>${org.seleniumhq-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>htmlunit-driver</artifactId>
        <version>2.23</version>
    </dependency>
```

The '*driver*' variable is initialized and Google Chrome is opened. Eclipse debugging shows exception occurs here `driver.get("https://www.google.co.in");`

Got two types of error in two times!. Both stacktrace are shown below.

> org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Error
>   communicating with the remote browser. It may have died.
>
> Build info:
>   version: '2.53.1', revision:
>   'a36b8b1cd5757287168e54b817830adce9b0158d', time: '2016-06-30
>   19:26:09' System info: host: 'fms-dev', ip: '192.168.1.56', os.name:
>   'Windows 8.1', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.3', java.version:
>   '1.8.0_101'
>
> Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver Capabilities
>   [{applicationCacheEnabled=false, rotatable=false,
>   chrome={userDataDir=C:\Users\fms\AppData\Local\Temp\scoped_dir3000_27723},
>   takesHeapSnapshot=true, databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=true,
>   version=54.0.2840.71, platform=WIN8_1, browserConnectionEnabled=false,
>   nativeEvents=true, acceptSslCerts=true, locationContextEnabled=true,
>   webStorageEnabled=true, browserName=chrome, takesScreenshot=true,
>   javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true}] Session ID:
>   05d03919d730cf29cb2267aba8f0de45  at
>
> org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:665)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.get(RemoteWebDriver.java:316)

Later i got this error

> org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error:
>   Runtime.executionContextCreated has invalid 'context':
>   {"auxData":{"frameId":"4492.1","isDefault":true},"id":1,"name":"","origin":"://"}
>
> (Session info: chrome=54.0.2840.71)   (Driver info:
>   chromedriver=2.9.248315,platform=Windows NT 6.3 x86_64) (WARNING: The
>   server did not provide any stacktrace information)
>
> Command duration or
>   timeout: 39 milliseconds Build info: version: '2.53.1', revision:
>   'a36b8b1cd5757287168e54b817830adce9b0158d', time: '2016-06-30
>   19:26:09' System info: host: 'dev-pc', ip: '192.168.1.56', os.name:
>   'Windows 8.1', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.3', java.version:
>   '1.8.0_101' Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
>   Capabilities [{applicationCacheEnabled=false, rotatable=false,
>   chrome={userDataDir=C:\Users\dev\AppData\Local\Temp\scoped_dir960_31279},
>   takesHeapSnapshot=true, databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=true,
>   version=54.0.2840.71, platform=WIN8_1, browserConnectionEnabled=false,
>   nativeEvents=true, acceptSslCerts=true, locationContextEnabled=true,
>   webStorageEnabled=true, browserName=chrome, takesScreenshot=true,
>   javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true}] Session ID:
>   a1f32c762f3525f55845afd4ab824af5  at
>
> sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:206)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:158)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:678)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.get(RemoteWebDriver.java:316)

On further research, i understand many had this issue, but I didn't get any solution except **incompatible version** issue. But i am using downloaded chromedriver.exe

**Also, earlier all the selenium steps had succeeded with this chrome driver and same selenium version.**. Don't know why this happened now! Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google Chrome installed in your windows system may have been updated automatically.
You can download the latest driver from the chrome driver website.

Comment: Downloaded latest chrome driver from [here](http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/). Now it's working.